# Using inherited interface in abstract method

Tags: c#, interface, abstract

Here's my code sample in C#:

```
abstract class A {
    public interface IA{

    }

    abstract protected void Print(IA obj);
}

abstract class B : A {
    public interface IB : IA{

    }

    override protected void Print(IB obj){
      // do something else
    }
}
```

Apparently, the compiler is not crazy about me overriding the Print method for the class B.

I am getting "no suitable method found to override."

Is there a way to make it work?  I am not looking for a design change, but a technical solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the method signature when you override it, and that's what you are doing by changing the argument type from `IA` to `IB`.

Lucky for you, you can use generics to solve this:

```
public interface IA{

}

public interface IB : IA{

}

abstract class A<T> where T : IA 
{
    abstract protected void Print(T obj);
}

abstract class B : A<IB> {

    override protected void Print(IB obj){
      // do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the kind of suggestion I am looking for.  However, the compiler doesn't see IB when I define the class B or I am missing something?

Comment: Did you try it and got a compiler error? I wrote the code directly here, so I might be wrong, however as far as I remember that's the way to handle such cases...

Comment: Yup, it's saying "The type or namespace name 'IB' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"  I even copied & pasted the name to make sure I didn't have a spelling error.  :)

Comment: probably because it's an inner type of the class. What if it would be a top level type?

Comment: yeah...it doesn't quite make sense to encapsulate the interfaces w/ the classes in this case.  I am separating the interfaces from the classes...Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: After the separation, your suggestion works.  Giving you credit for it.

Comment: Glad to help :-)

Comment: @JohnnyWu I've updated the code in my answer to reflect that. Would you mind taking a look to see that I didn't miss anything (and fix if I did), so that future readers might also benefit from this answer?

Comment: confirmed...that's exactly what I have...I am not sure if you are getting the credit, but an unkind marked my question as duplicate which.  I'll reserve my comment about that.  If you don't get the credit, I am sorry.

Comment: @JohnnyWu credit is not that important, but yes, I do get it even if the question is a duplicate. It's impossible to add new answers to a closed question, but every existing answer is just like on an open question.

Answer (score 0):

This is very weird design, but you can achieve this by:

```
   abstract class A {
    public interface IA{

    }

    abstract protected void Print(IA obj);
}

abstract class B : A {
    public interface IB : IA{

    }

    override protected void Print(IA obj){
    }

    protected void Print(IB obj){
      Print(obj as IA);
    }
}
```